# Generate barcode in pdf - Angular 4+ ngx-barcode

Tags: angular, pdf, barcode

PDF Library: JSPDF

Framework: Angular 4

Issue: Unable to generate a barcode on PDF.

When a user clicks the download button, I want a pdf containing their barcode saved. The barcode is not generated onto the html file before the pdf is generated.

TRY 1:

I tried using addFont for JSPDF, like so (the ttf is the ean13 type). The snippet where I try to add the barcode font:

```
 this.doc.addFont('./ean13.ttf', 'barcode', 'normal');
      this.doc.setFont('barcode');
      this.doc.text("hello", 140, 50);
```

It doesnt output the barcode, instead it just displays "hello". I tried using ngx-barcode, but it requires that we use:

TRY 2:

```
<ngx-barcode [bc-value]="value" [bc-display-value]="true"></ngx-barcode>
```

in the html file to generate the barcode, but I want it to be directly printed into the pdf.

Comment: You are aware that the EAN13 barcode is numeric only?

Comment: Apparently not! But when I replace the earlier code with this:  
      this.doc.text("123344", 140, 50); I get just 123344. No Barcode. Probably the font is broken. Ill check. Thanks

Comment: I don't use fonts for barcodes that require an algorithm because it isn't just a matter of character / glyph replacement. If you need to use EAN-13, you have to have javascript compute the checksum and convert the numbers required to get the left and right hand side of the symbol translated. Besides that you need 12 digits (no more, no less) in addition to the checksum (that's what the 13 stands for). My codepen that does this with plain vanilla JavaScript: https://codepen.io/notionovus/pen/KXEWdK

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I need to print barcode with ngx-barcode and I have exactly the problem that you had?

Comment: It was too much effort. I had the option of skipping the barcode and went for a QR code.